# How to send multiple items to PayPal

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I want to send multiple item names and item prices to PayPal but I am unable to post my item name and price with below code can you please help me?

```
<form method="post"  name="cart" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_xclick">
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="navive_1295939206_biz@gmail.com">
    <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">

    <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
    <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
    <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://newzonemedia.com/henry/ipn.php" />
    <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
    <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.example.com/thank_you_kindly.html" />


    <?php
    //select items for table
    $srowcart_dtl = mysql_num_rows($srscart_dtl);
    if($srowcart_dtl > 0) {
        $cnt=1;
        while($srscart_dtl1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($srscart_dtl)) {
            ?>  
            <input type="hidden" name="item_name[<?php echo $cnt ?>]" value="<?php echo $srscart_dtl1['cart_iname']; ?>">

            <input type="hidden" name="amount[<?php echo $cnt ?>]" value="<?php echo $srscart_dtl1['cart_iprc']; ?>">
            <?php
            $cnt++;
        }
    }
    ?>
    <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
    <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

Comment: how are you checking the value on the server ?

Comment: i checked values, values are manually inserted in table. just i am testing, i have item nave and price in table.

Answer (score 13):

Create your code like this:

```
<form action="https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr" method="post">
    <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">  <!-- change _xclick to _cart -->
    <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">  <!-- add this line in your code -->
    <input type="hidden" name="business" value="your_seller_account">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_1" value="Item Name 1">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_1" value="1.00">
    <input type="hidden" name="item_name_2" value="Item Name 2">
    <input type="hidden" name="amount_2" value="2.00">
    <input type="submit" value="PayPal">
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, you for make mention of the `cmd field` +1

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the changes suggested by devilprince, the underscores are missing from the line item input tags' name attributes, and also the tags are not proper self-closing tags because the closing `/` is missing. Correct like so:

```
<form method="post" name="cart" action="https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr">
  <input type="hidden" name="cmd" value="_cart">
  <input type="hidden" name="upload" value="1">
  <input type="hidden" name="business" value="navive_1295939206_biz@gmail.com">
  <input type="hidden" name="lc" value="US">
  <input type="hidden" name="currency_code" value="USD">
  <input type="hidden" name="button_subtype" value="services">
  <input type="hidden" name="notify_url" value="http://newzonemedia.com/henry/ipn.php" />
  <input type="hidden" name="bn" value="PP-BuyNowBF:btn_buynowCC_LG.gif:NonHosted">
  <input type="hidden" name="return" value="http://www.mysite.org/thank_you_kindly.html" />

  <?php
    // select items for table
    $srowcart_dtl = mysql_num_rows($srscart_dtl);
    if($srowcart_dtl > 0)
    {
       $cnt=1;
       while($srscart_dtl1 = mysql_fetch_assoc($srscart_dtl))
       {
  ?>    
         <input type="hidden" name="item_name_[<?php echo $cnt ?>]" value="<?php echo $srscart_dtl1['cart_iname']; ?>"/>
         <input type="hidden" name="amount_[<?php echo $cnt ?>]" value="<?php echo $srscart_dtl1['cart_iprc']; ?>"/>
  <?php
         $cnt++;
       }
    }
  ?>
  <input type="image" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/btn/btn_buynowCC_LG.gif" border="0" name="submit" alt="PayPal - The safer, easier way to pay online!">
  <img alt="" border="0" src="https://www.paypal.com/en_US/i/scr/pixel.gif" width="1" height="1">
</form>
```

(You may also want to escape special characters in the value attribute, at least for the `"` character in case it shows up in your item name data.)

Just had to figure this out today for a client. Besides `item_name_N` and `amount_N` I also used `quantity_N`, `tax_N`, and `shipping_N` (where N is the line item number, starting with 1).

This page has a list of all parameters: [PayPal HTML Form Variables](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/paypal-payments-standard/integration-guide/Appx_websitestandard_htmlvariables), but the question & answers given here are a better real-world example than the trivial examples on the PayPal site.