# Paypal standard or Payments Pro

Tags: php, paypal, payment

I'm currently using the standard cart function from paypal (using my own PHP to configure the data and price details) to create a shopping cart for services (based off this post: [How to send multiple items to PayPal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4791004/how-to-send-multiple-items-to-paypal)).

However, I need to show the full item price and the deposit amount, and only charge the user the deposit amount. Currently, I have the Deposit Amount set as the Item Price, but I think that will be confusing to users since it doesn't show the full item price. I need to show both the Item Price as the full amount of the product, and then have another label for Deposit Amount that is used as the amount that is charged.

For example, this is what I need to show:

```
**Service 1** 

Item Price: $500

Deposit Amount: $200
___
**Amount Due Now: $200**

Balance Remaining: $300
___
```

I haven't seen a way to do this using the standard cart function, and was wondering if it's possible to customize these type of variables using Payments Pro.

Answer (score 0):

You can use PayPal Payments Pro or Express Checkout.

Express Checkout allows you to set the call (from the PayPal Developer Documentation)

1. Call `SetExpressCheckout` to set up the transaction and define the URL to which the customer is returned after the customer authorizes payment.
2. Redirect the customer to PayPal for authorization of the payment.
3. Call `GetExpressCheckoutDetails` to obtain customer information, e.g. for customer review before payment. (returns to your website, and send the payment details to your cart)
4. Call `DoExpressCheckoutPayment` to complete the transaction.

In the return page you can present the final payment amount to the buyer, which will allow you to charge the deposit amount.

Here is the getting started Guide for Express Checkout, which has a complete picture of the typical Express Checkout Flow

[Express Checkout Getting Started](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/gs_expresscheckout)

You can use the Code Wizard to generate Express Checkout Code.
[Integration Wizard](https://devtools-paypal.com/integrationwizard/ecpaypal/main.php)

Express checkout also allows for recurring payments if you need to charge someone a deposit now, and then the rest of the payment at a later date. Here is the integration guide for Express Checkout Recurring Payments

[Express Checkout Recurring Payments Developer Guide](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/express-checkout/integration-guide/ECRecurringPayments)

If you would prefer to use PayPal Payments Pro Payflow edition you can create a custom cart that keeps your buyer's on your website and allows you to charge the card the deposit amount. PayPal Payments Pro Payflow Edition does have recurring payments as an option as well.

Here is the getting started overview for Payflow Pro

[Payflow Pro Getting Started Overview](https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/payflow/gs_payflow/)

Here is the [Payflow Pro Developer Guide](https://www.paypalobjects.com/webstatic/en_US/developer/docs/pdf/payflowgateway_guide.pdf)